# Could not parse POM when upgrading AGP with upgrade assistant

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to upgrade my AGP from 7.2.0 to 7.4.2 using the AGP assistant in Android Studio, this is the error I'm getting:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom
            > Resetting to invalid mark
```

I'm setting proxy at global gradle.properties and android studio settings, I can confirm that I can download a healthy gradle-7.4.2.pom when I navigate the said link with my browser, thank you for any insights

this is in my application gradle.build

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}
```

this is for a flutter project, there is no problem with my 7.2.0 AGP
Also I'm using gradle 7.5 as mentioned in my gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```